# Encontrar conjunto de puntos con la misma distancia en una matriz euclidiana python

Tags: python

Tengo una lista con coordenadas y está matriz euclidiana representa la distancia que hay entre cada punto:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]]

 [[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 1. 0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 2. 1. 0. 1.]
 [4. 3. 2. 1. 0.]]
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es saber cuántos segmentos de recta existen con la misma distancia y si coinciden en un punto intermedio, por ejemplo: Como podemos ver en la siguiente imagen de la coordenada (0,0) a la coordenada (0,1) hay una distancia igual a 1 y de la coordenada (0,2) a la coordenada (0,1) hay una distancia igual a 1 (ya tenemos dos segmentos de recta con la misma distancia) y ambos comparten un punto en la coordenada (0, 1).

Tal y cómo muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero como salida es el numero de casos que coincide con los requisitos que mencione anteriormente, en la imagen de arriba podemos ver que son 4 casos en los que coincide con los requisitos.

Cómo se implementaría en python? Y existe alguna librería que facilite este análisis?

Comment: En el caso de la matriz que tienes como ejemplo, ¿Cuales son los puntos que analizas?, ¿Cual es la salida que esperas? deberias editar tu pregunta y hacerla mas compresible

Comment: Tienes razón, formule mal mi explicación, ya lo edite y creo que ahora se entiende un poco mejor.